# Send data asynchronously from server to client

Tags: servlets, asynchronous, server-push

I have a client app that invoke a Java Servlet end-point to download some information. The servlet itself needs to collect the informtaion from different backend systems, assemble it in the correct form and then respond to the client. Since this is time-consuming I would like to implement it in a manner that the user does not have to wait for a response from the server. I was thinking of implementing the following approach:

1. Client makes a call to the Servlet
2. Servlet generates a Unique Key and passes the key to the client, requesting the client to poll with the key after sometime
3. Servlet meanwhile performs the computations and then stores the information in a cache against the key
4. Client periodically polls the servlet with the key to see if data is available and if available get the data

Are there any better ways of doing this kind of an orchestration between client and the server?

Comment: how about implementing any Message Queueing systems like activemq,rabbitmq

Comment: My query is more about the client to server interaction rather than how to do the computations in the server side. There I have multiple options as you mentioned, or even a simple ExecutorService would be suffice.